# Power Bi cumulative line chart dynamical axis

Tags: datetime, powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop, cumulative-line-chart

[The graph already done here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wMVgc.png)
Hello in power Bi i am creating a chart with cumulative measure of sales by creation date for a given arrival motnh (orseveral month via a slicer) But get stuck with continous line when date of arrival is > date of création
i got a continuous line

I succefully adpat the x axis maximum to the max date of réservation via a measure

```
Max Date with CA = 
CALCULATE(
    MAX('Feuil1'[date de réservation commune]),
    FILTER(
        ALL('Feuil1'),
        [Cumul CA] > 0
    ),
    'Feuil1'[date d'arrivée] = SELECTEDVALUE('Feuil1'[date d'arrivée])
)
```

In the screen shot you can see that after the 31 of january no more sales have benne made for the arrival month of january so no use to continue to see the line..
My cumulative measures is the Following

```
Cumul CA = 
VAR SelectedDate = MAX('Feuil1'[date de réservation commune])
RETURN
CALCULATE(
    [CA TTC], 
    FILTER(
        ALL('Feuil1'), 
        'Feuil1'[date de réservation commune] <= SelectedDate
    )
)
```

Thanks in advance

So i need that for the current year the chart stop displaying the line when max of current year sales amount is reached.